# Convert number to letters using dictionary in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have input that provides a number and a sequence of distinct letters (upper/lowercase).

The program generates a dictionary for provided sequence of letters and the number should be converted using into letters using values from dictionary.

For example, I have following input:

```
Convert 49036 using fFeEdDcCbBaA.
```

The dictionary created for this sequence of letters is:

```
numberkey = {500000: 'f', 100000: 'F', 50000: 'e', 10000: 'E', 5000: 'd', 1000: 'D', 500: 'c', 100: 'C', 50: 'b', 10: 'B', 5: 'a', 1: 'A'}
```

The output of the conversion should be this:

```
EeDEBBBaA
```

*Roman number conversion rules applies.*

The output I'm getting so far is not correct:

```
EEEEdDDDDBBBaA
```

Would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: what's the different of EEEE (10,000+10,000+10,000+10,000)and Ee (50,000 - 10,000)?

Comment: @ZhubeiFederer Similar to how Roman numerals work

Comment: Using Roman numbers conversion rules. Ee is complying with the rule - If a symbol of smaller value is written to the left of a symbol of greater value, its value is subtracted from the value of the greater symbol. While EEEE is not, because the same symbol is repeated more than 3 times. I will update the question now.

Comment: got it,but 
since you know this is  Roman numerals problem, there is many method in google search:https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/class-exercises/python-class-exercise-2.php

Comment: @ZhubeiFederer the only problem with that is, these approaches strictly work with the Roman numeral only

Comment: @ZhubeiFederer yes, the code I provided works fine with Roman numerals, but for this one output is incorrect and I run out of ways to make it work right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple and generalised approach, based on the Roman Numeral concept.

```py
n = 49036
numberkey = {500000: 'f', 100000: 'F', 50000: 'e', 10000: 'E', 5000: 'd', 1000: 'D', 500: 'c', 100: 'C', 50: 'b', 10: 'B', 5: 'a', 1: 'A'}
x = list(numberkey.items())
x.sort()
new_base = []    #to get special symbols for 4's and 9's
for i in range(len(x)-1):
    if x[i][0] < (x[i+1][0]/2):
        new_base.append((x[i+1][0]-x[i][0], x[i][1]+x[i+1][1]))
    if (str(x[i][0]).find("10")==0) and numberkey.get(x[i][0]//10, None):
        num = numberkey[x[i][0]//10]
        new_base.append((x[i][0]-(x[i][0]//10), num+x[i][1]))

x += new_base
x.sort()
ans = ""
i = len(x)-1
while n and i>=0:
    count = n//x[i][0]
    if count:
        ans += count*x[i][1]
        n -= count*x[i][0]
    i -= 1

print(and)   #EeDEBBBaA
```